# Object does not support this property or method - IE8 only?

Tags: javascript

I have cross browser tested a page which contains a jslider. It functions as expected in all browsers/versions except IE8 which throws a script error, *"Object does not support this property or method"*. When I run the build in IE script debug facility it identifies the issue to be with line `element.attachEvent("on" + actualEventName, responder)` in the following function (this line of code is the last line before the function return):

```
function observe(element, eventName, handler) {
element = $(element);

var responder = _createResponder(element, eventName, handler);

if (!responder) return element;

if (eventName.include(':')) {
  if (element.addEventListener)
    element.addEventListener("dataavailable", responder, false);
  else {
    element.attachEvent("ondataavailable", responder);
    element.attachEvent("onlosecapture", responder);
  }
} else {
  var actualEventName = _getDOMEventName(eventName);

  if (element.addEventListener)
    element.addEventListener(actualEventName, responder, false);
  else
    element.attachEvent("on" + actualEventName, responder);
}

return element;
}
```

Any ideas what the issue may be?

Comment: This is no jQuery, this is standard Javascript. If you would use jQuery you can just do `$(element).bind("click", handler);`

Answer (score 0):

_getDOMEventName() Does that return a value?